# Is there a name for the property, such as for f-means, that the result lies in the closed interval between the minimum and maximum of the input set?

Tags: statistics, functions, terminology, average, means

> All the possible [f-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean) (a broad generalization of the [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)) have the property that the result is in the closed interval between min and max of the input set. I've found this property mentioned in several places, but it is never given a name. Is there a name for this?

I'd consider "convexity" (since the result is a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of the inputs), but that word already has a [different meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) when it comes to functions.

Comment: Please spell out what you mean.  Not everyone knows the term "f-means".

Comment: It follows from Kolmogorov's axioms of monotonicity and fixed point. There is no established name, you can call it "intermediacy", for example. A generalization would be set maps that take values in the convex hull of the set (like center of mass), there is no name for those either.